# display text in certain format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 5 for application and I have a table in which one record contains a string with formatted text like this

```
<p><span style="font-size: large;">Good Morning.. Its April 15 today! HAve a nice day..</span></p> <h3></h3> <p><span style="font-size: large;"><br /></span></p>
```

now when displaying the text in view i need to show the text in the format written inside the record like suppose for above i need like

**Good Morning.... Its April 15 today! hava a nice day....**

[note: font size is large >

Comment: have you tried Html.Raw?  what are you seeing instead of what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have a string which has text as "<p>good</p>" meaning string containing the html format text. now when displaying that string i want to show the formatted text i.e. "good" but its showing same thing "<p>good</p>"

Comment: And could you tell me how to use html.raw and what it does? i am new to this subject.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx